# Sugar CRM theme wont change

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I am trying to override the default Sugar5 theme and I believe it worked. But its not picking up on my css. My theme directory looks like this

> themes/mytheme
>
> themes/mytheme/themedef.php
>
> themes/mytheme/css/
>
> themes/mytheme/css/style.css
>
> themes/mytheme/themedef.php

```
<?php
if(!defined('sugarEntry') || !sugarEntry) die('Not A Valid Entry Point');
/*********************************************************************************
 [ legal boiler plate removed ]
********************************************************************************/


$themedef = array(
'parentTheme' => "Sugar5",
'name'  => "mytheme",
'description' => "Enhanced Brands",
'version' => array(
    'regex_matches' => array('6\.*.*'),
    ),
);
```

But its not picking up on my css folder
So I went into config.php and changed the default_theme to mytheme
Still nothing. any ideas whats next ??

Comment: I've removed the sugar legal boilerplate. there's no need to include such things in a question, especially when it hides your actual code far down the page.

Comment: Check that your user Theme preference is not conflicting with your Admin Theme. That's what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

some suggestions:

- Isn't the parentTheme called "Classic"? (And not "Sugar5")
- Rebuild SugarCRM via the admin->Repair to rebuild files
- Make sure you clean any browser cache (since css usually are cached)
- Enable developer mode in Sugar to disable any caching
- Use Firebug or similar to ensure the css is loaded properly

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you'll want to do a 'Quick Rebuild and Repair' in the Admin -> Repair section to pick up your new theme and any changes to it. Also, clearing out your browser cache will help as well.

Also, make sure the permission on your css file and css/ folder both allow read access to the webserver user.

Answer (score 0):

@Kåre W. Storgaard /themes/Sugar5 is the correct theme to be changing code wise, its called "Classic" in the Interface.

However you really shouldn't be doing it in the /themes folder as this may be over written in future updates.

Instead copy the classic theme to /custom/themes/{your new theme name}, then switch the theme over to it in the user control panel.

Another thing to watch is some css in the default theme is declared twice!